# How to add custom nameserver under /etc/resolv.conf into pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

which service assigns nameservers under  /etc/resolv.conf of pods , generally it should pickup from host /etc/resolv.conf , i'm seeing different nameservers under /etc/resolv.conf of pods, is there is any configuration on kbernetes(kubedns) which i can configure so that  pods   /etc/resolv.conf have 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1.- To put it in a `configMap`, and map it to `/etc/resolv.conf`, in which case it will be replaced by the content in the `configMap`.

2.- You can do this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
  dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 8.8.8.8
```

This way you are mapping whatever is in `dnsConfig` under `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

There is another way actually, by "hacking" kube-dns, for `upstreamNameservers`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  upstreamNameservers: |
    ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
```

But in this case you wouldn't be doing anything within the pod (so `/etc/resolv.conf` would not be modified), but `kube-dns` would use these nameservers to resolve.

Comment: Thanks  is it possible to add dns configuration under                                         podTemplate(label: label, 
            containers: [ 
               containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.5-jdk-8', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true) ],

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue over Jenkins deployed on Kubernetes. If you don't mention a nameserver then */etc/resolv.conf* shows the default nameserver (ip of k8s).
I solved this by modifying the deploy file with

```
      dnsPolicy: "None"
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
          - 8.8.8.8
```

and applying it.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        ports:
          - name: http-port
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: jnlp-port
            containerPort: 50000
        volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-vol
            mountPath: /var/jenkins_vol
      dnsPolicy: "None"
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
          - 8.8.8.8    
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-vol
          emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: You saved my day :) , tried 2 full day to resolve this error even chat gpt did't solve my solution , now my all outbound are working thanks

Answer (score 3):

`kube-dns` does modify this file (via Kubelet). `kube-dns` watches API server and observes changes to Service and Endpoints and keeps DNS records up to date.
Within Cluster you should use internal Kubernetes DNS.

DNS is add-on controller, you can use any other implementation.

Take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy).

If you want to override kube-dns

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: dns-example
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: nginx
  dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 1.2.3.4
    searches:
      - ns1.svc.cluster-domain.example
      - my.dns.search.suffix
    options:
      - name: ndots
        value: "2"
      - name: edns0
```

[DNS Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy)

Comment: can you provide any information that backs up this theory? never heard of **kube-dns** modifying `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Comment: @suren Definitely, that is done indirectly through Kubelet.

Comment: I don't think so. I would say you are confusing `kube-dns` with `kube-proxy`.

Comment: I believe kube-proxy (in current implementation) would only modify iptables.

Comment: So, have you read it anywhere that `kube-dns` modifies (directly or indirectly) `resolv.conf` file? Because "Definitely" sounds pretty confident, and it simply doesn't make any sense.

Comment: For example : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-kubernetes-dns-service 

_italic_ The kube-dns service listens for service and endpoint events from the Kubernetes API and updates its DNS records as needed. These events are triggered when you create, update or delete Kubernetes services and their associated pods.
kubelet sets each new pod’s /etc/resolv.conf nameserver option to the cluster IP of the kube-dns service, with appropriate search options to allow for shorter hostnames to be used:  _italic_

Comment: Which, by no means, says that `kube-dns` modifies anything within the pod. `kube-dns` modifies it's own records, as it is logical, since service names need to be resolved. Anyways, I think your post is not answering the question. It just gives general info about `kube-dns`.

Comment: No component modifies anything on a pod. All them write desired state to etcd via API server.

Comment: what has to do the desired state of a pod with dns? That's metadata. Let's leave this here please.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/#why-does-kubelet-manage-the-hosts-file

Comment: Your first copy-paste was already stating that kubelet is the guy managing the file. May be you could edit your answer, which is straight wrong.

Comment: It is not wrong. From Kubernetes.io : Kubernetes DNS schedules a DNS Pod and Service on the cluster, and configures the kubelets to tell individual containers to use the DNS Service’s IP to resolve DNS names... Kubelet manages the hosts file for each container of the Pod to prevent Docker from modifying the file after the containers have already been started.

Answer (score -1):

Starting with k8s 1.9, if you want to set a specific dns config for a pod, you can use [dns policy None](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

It allows a Pod to ignore DNS settings from the Kubernetes environment. All DNS settings are supposed to be provided using the dnsConfig field in the Pod Spec.

by default, The nameserver IP is the Kubernetes service IP of kube-dns

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5

kubectl get service -n kube-system
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   2d21h
```

with this configuration in the deployment section:

```
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 8.8.8.8
  dnsPolicy: "None"
```

`cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score -1):

@venkatesh I think you are referring to podTemplate() used inside a jenkins file.
If thats the case try this

```
podTemplate( yaml:"""
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:trusty
    command: ["echo"]
    args: ["Hello World"]
 dnsPolicy: "None"
 dnsConfig:
   nameservers:
   - 8.8.8.8
""")
```

a yaml file can be used directly inside a jenkins file as a template.
More examples are present in https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/examples/ .