# Rancher node: Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted

Tags: rancher, rancher-rke

I was running into:
`Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted`. I am experiencing this for my pods on two of my nodes. Three other nodes (their pods) don't have this issue.

The pods are configured with
`ClusterFirst` `dnsPolicy`, so they got the nameserver of the node they are scheduled on.

```
/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf containted:
nameserver 2a01:xxx:xxxx::add:1
nameserver 2a01:xxx:xxxx::add:2
nameserver 185.XX.XX.X
Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 185.XX.XX.X
```

I was able to remove the two IPv6 addresses via `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` as of course the default limit is 3 https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/7ruq0f/kubelet_nameserver_limits_were_exceeded/

What is the best way to solve this within Kubernetes?

This does not feel the best way to me:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70969023/1766764

My other nodes don't need this and diffing the node yaml files did not reveal any differences in this direction (no nameserver explicitly configured).

```
Ubuntu 20.4 and Rancher v1.19.6-rancher1-1 is used
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar case with the DualStack network with DHCP for both IPv4 & IPv6, and both were advertising two nameservers each, resulting in 4 nameservers on the host. And k8s DNS is pulling nameservers from the host.

After removing one DNS nameserver from the router's configuration for each IPv4 & IPv6 DHCP server, the message "Nameserver limits were exceeded, some nameservers have been omitted" disappeared.